I’m cheering them on!
1:

3:

5:

Can you determine what’s next?

Clarification:  In a comment I was asked if the [knowledge] tag should be added to this puzzle:
Since no special knowledge is necessary to solve this puzzle, I don’t think the [knowledge] tag is necessary. However a bit of knowledge is necessary to understand the hint provided in the title but I can imagine people solving this puzzle without understanding the hint.

Should the knowledge tag be added?

@PDT Since no special knowledge is necessary to solve this puzzle, I don’t think the knowledge tag is necessary.  However a bit of knowledge is necessary to understand the hint provided in the title but I can imagine people solving this puzzle without understanding the hint.

These diagrams represent

 best-of-$n$ matches,

specifically

 the sequences of game winners, represented as a downward path with each branch leaning left or right to show who wins. The path ends where one team has won over $n/2$ games and so clinches the series.

For the next element in the series,

 representing best-of-$7$ games, I don't have time now to draw the tree, but here's a list of branches going left to right generated by code. There are 70 of them, of which 40 go to game 7.

The title "I’m cheering them on!" presumably refers to the

 ongoing playoffs of NBA basketball, where teams plays each other in best-of-7 series, or maybe just sports matches in general.


+1 rot13(Gur gvgyr ersref gb fcbegf zngpurf va trareny.)

Not American enough to have worked this out. Cool puzzle though.

@PDT I’m glad you liked it.  By the way, I’m Canadian.

@PDT I didn't really use any specific knowledge to solve this. I figured out what property describes where the paths end, then connected it to the context where it comes up.

Here is one created for the "Best-of-7 Major League Baseball World Series" that I found online:
Google Images


@WillOctagonGibson Wow, good eye! I didn't even notice that, but I should have, since it wasn't even symmetrical. Fixed now.

@WillOctagonGibson Thx for the 250 rep pts. Seems high for the small amount of effort involved, but I'll take it!
